# Is there a way to keep repeating command blocks always running (even if the chunk it is in unloads)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This might just be asking how to keep chunks always loaded, but there's a bit more to this question.

I have a command block (repeating) that is always running a command that will detect if a specifically-renamed item (a feather that is renamed 'Feather of the Skies') is not in the offhand slot, and if it is not there, then it clears a specific potion effect (in this case, levitation)

Here is the command I am running currently (it runs fine):

```
/effect clear @a[nbt=!{SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:feather",tag:{display:{Name:"\"Feather of the Skies\""}}}}] minecraft:levitation
```

However, whenever I leave my base, the chunk that the command block is in unloads, and renders the detector/command block useless. Is there any way to make this command block stay unloaded, or is there any alternative solution so that the command does not have to stay in a chunk to work? (maybe something like a scoreboard?)

In other words, is there a way to either keep this chunk always loaded **OR** is there a way to make the command run regardless of your location in the world?

I am playing on Minecraft Java Edition, on ver. 1.14.4, and the world is completely vanilla, if this information is needed.

Comment: Use a mod with chunk loaders?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The chunks surrounding the [world spawn](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#World_spawn) are always loaded, so this is the best place to put command blocks that you always want to run.  You can change where the world span is using the [`/setworldspawn` command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/setworldspawn).

However, the better option in this case is to put your commands in a [function file](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Function_(Java_Edition)) and load it through a [datapack](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_pack).  Google search offers a [number of tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=mcfunction+tutorial) for how to do this.