# Do command blocks stop working at a certain distance?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

This is regarding Minecraft: Bedrock Edition. I am trying to automatically change players to adventure mode when when entering a town and back to survival mode when leaving. I created a function which is executing in a repeating command block. The below commands basically create 2 towns. If player 1 goes into player 2 town it puts them in adventure mode. When player 1 enters their own town it puts them in creative mode. Leaving both towns will put them in survival mode.

```
#run this one time to create a townMode variable
#scoreboard objectives add townMode dummy 

scoreboard players set @a[scores={townMode=!0}] townMode 0

#town for player 1
scoreboard players set @a[name=player1name, scores={townMode=!1}, x=501, y=62, z=151, dx=49, dy=49, dz=49] townMode 1
scoreboard players set @a[name=!player1name, scores={townMode=!2}, x=501, y=62, z=151, dx=49, dy=49, dz=49] townMode 2

#town for player 2
scoreboard players set @a[name=player2name, scores={townMode=!1}, x=501, y=62, z=93, dx=49, dy=49, dz=49] townMode 1
scoreboard players set @a[name=!player2name, scores={townMode=!2}, x=501, y=62, z=93, dx=49, dy=49, dz=49] townMode 2

gamemode 0 @a[scores={townMode=0},m=!0]
gamemode 1 @a[scores={townMode=1},m=!1]
gamemode 2 @a[scores={townMode=2},m=!2]
```

Its basically working BUT I noticed that the command block stops executing the commands if I am too far away. If I put the command block in the center of the town it works but if I put it really far away it doesn't seem to trigger consistently. I noticed this after a few hours beating my head against the table. I saw via commandblockoutput the commands stop running if I'm too far from the command block. Is there any workaround where I can have the command block far from the villages but still work?

Comment: If the chunks aren't always loaded, the command blocks there will stop running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alas in bedrock command blocks do not stay loaded when you get too far away even if placed in the world spawn area. I tried it experimentally and the commands stop running if I get too far away. I however did find this [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/comments/bssg0t/how_to_keep_command_blocks_loaded/) which says you can add up to 10 'ticking areas'. This works like a charm in bedrock! Will upvote the answers since the do look like they would work in java edition and you led me in the right direction.

/tickingarea x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 chunkName

Comment: Ahh, this makes sense! This is a great solution, if you want you can checkmark yourself :D

Answer (score 4):

Command blocks follow the same rules as other blocks, in that they will stop running if the chunk they are located in is unloaded.

[This question asked something similar.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/368389/is-there-a-way-to-keep-repeating-command-blocks-always-running-even-if-the-chun) One solution that was suggested there, by @MBraedley:

> The chunks surrounding the [world spawn](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#World_spawn) are always loaded, so this is the best place to put command blocks that you always want to run. You can change where the world spawn is using the `/setworldspawn` command.

Comment: Dude that is a pro tip thanks! Will try it out and give the credit if it works. Was worried I would have to put command blocks every 50 squares in the whole world

Comment: Glad I could help :)