# In a given location, how can I give a player some item?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I want to make some minigame where players can get a certain item when they get into a specific location, where then they can craft with it and then PVP.

So I thought of using the `/execute` command to then `/give` them with that specific coordinate.

```
/execute @a x y z give @p stick
```

Putting this in an Always Active Repeating Command Block, it still gives me the item even if I'm not in that location.

How can I give items to a player in they're in the given coordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the command:
`/execute @e[x=#,y=#,z=#,dx=#,dy=#,dz=#] ~ ~ ~ give @s stick`

Substitute the # hashtags for coordinates, and everything prefixed with d for distances.

Comment: There's no `distance` attribute in Bedrock. Also, there's no `as` component in `/execute`.

Comment: Are you sure? this question https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/380383/do-command-blocks-stop-working-at-a-certain-distance seems to say there is, see the command in the question body

Comment: I am referring to the first part of his sentence about distance, I think distance is shown in that question's body

Comment: I mean see the command in the question code block right under `#town for player 1`'s selector

Comment: @RayWu Yes, I see lots of arguments but no `distance ` one.

Comment: I thin I fixed the bedrock but you have to replace #

Comment: @rayWu instead of distance bedrock just has `rm` and `r`

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using two command blocks, one repeating and one chain command block. One way is to put the command blocks under that specific area or another way is to not put it under that specific area but make it act upon the that area.

First, you need to lay out both command blocks assigned to **one direction**. Then make both blocks **“Always Active”**.
Make the chain command block set to **“Conditional”**.

## Repeating Command Block

Type in `/testfor @a[x=?,y=?,z=?,r=?]`  (if your command blocks are under the specific area, you don’t need to type in the coordinates except the ‘r’ value)

## Chain Command Block Or Comparator

For this stage, you can either place a redstone comparator out of the repeating command block activating other blocks or place the chain command block. In the chain command block, just type in `/give @p stick`

Answer (score 0):

Oh wait, I just realised that a much more easier way to do this is just place a *repeating command block* that is **’Always Active’** and just type in `/give @a[x=?,y=?,z=?,r=?] stick`