# How to give a player a specific item in a specific location? (Java Edition)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I started playing Java Edition months ago after being a Bedrock player for so long. Since I'm new to Java, commands are still pretty fuzzy to me.

In this question, I'm trying to reaccomplish what I've done [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/382501/264127) from Bedrock Edition into Java. Why? I'm currently making the game there with a friend.

So if in Bedrock, it goes like this:

```
/execute @a[x=#,y=#,z=#,dx=0,dy=0,dz=0] ~ ~ ~ give @s []
```

There should be something similar in Java, but I can't properly configure the `execute` command there.

What would be the equivalent of that given command into Java? Do I need multiple commands to get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the execute command in Java edition is a little different to bedrock edition.
You can read about it on the wiki [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/execute#Java_Edition)

This command should work for what you want.

```
execute as @a[x=<x>,y=<y>,z=<z>] run give @s minecraft:<item>
```